# Time until voting starts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

Shouldn't the ability to vote(up/down) begin only after a particular amount of time has lapsed since the initial post? Same is true for accepting an answer to a question, both of which you yourself have posted or is answered by someone else. I think the reasoning behind those limitations would easily apply here as well.

Comment: Do you really _need_ to read Shog's post on community management. It's not like you're going to disagree with him often :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards skepticism and honest judgment/appraisal should always be there. Votes should be wisely used ;)

Comment: Don't forget that the mods and admins talk behind closed doors. So it's possible that they discussed this in private already. So when Shog posted the answer, they already knew what he was gonna say so they upvoted.

Comment: So lets say that you delay voting for, what, 20 seconds, 30 seconds?  Any more than that and for shorter posts people can clearly read it in far less time.  If you have a wait that's that short it's a minor annoyance, but it's highly unlikely to change how anyone acts.  What's gained?

Comment: There was a smiley face @hus787... I wasn't being literal and have actually downvoted his posts before (don't kill me!). Fun fact, that comment got an upvote within 5 seconds...

Comment: @Mysticial There were quite a few people actively participating in the question at the time it was posted.  I know I saw it within a second or two of it being posted and read the whole thing in somewhere between 5 and 10 seconds before voting, and was one of the first handful of voters.  Were it an older post not being so actively discussed *in real time* it would be more surprising.

Comment: I want to downvote posts that deserve it within seconds. Often you can see that instantly.

Comment: FYI it took me about 8 seconds to read this and decide I disagree with it.

Answer (score 7):

I want to reassure all of you that I neither passed around a link to my answer internally, nor enjoy any special privilege as far as up-votes go.

However, I can neither confirm nor deny the existence of a bug that generates an automatic up-vote for each use of the question-asker's name in an answer, hus787.

You'll just have to figure that one out for yourself. Hus787.

Comment: Only one upvote and I see the name twice... :)

Comment: I never intended to say, or even allude to that

Comment: @Mysticial - Must be case sensitive.

Comment: @hus787 You said, quote "Was it a real vote?"

Comment: @MartinSmith Godammit... :)

Comment: Case-sensetive bug must have been fixed just now.

Comment: @JoshC yup, "real vote" I meant. How does that allude to the fact that was putting it on the poster?